# How to destroy VOIP phone in a proper way?

Tags: physical, data-leakage, voip

Are there any standards which consider safe **destroying of VOIP phones**? I would like to prevent eventual data leakage after devices which have left the company.

Comment: *Do your VOIP phones actually store any data?*  Ours don't.  They pull all of the necessary data from the server on boot, including extension number, Caller ID, phonebook, speed dial, and call history (the server provides these based on the MAC address of the phone).  The only thing stored in the phone itself is the (private) IP address of the server and VLAN number they should be on, neither of which is at all useful without already being on the office network.

Comment: I'm pretty sure fire will destroy it, if set hot enough and long enough. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering every VOIP phone is different, it's kind of hard to standardize depending on where the storage module is located.

There are companies who are specialized in hardware destruction, opting for performing destruction yourself can be *very very* tricky. Should you be able to locate the storage module you could use the [Guidelines for Media Sanitization](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-88/NISTSP800-88_with-errata.pdf) produced by NIST.

Comment: I'd say remove the data storage module and perform whatever safe practices there are for that particular type of data storage hardware...

Comment: Figuring out if you can trust that company is even harder than figuring out how to destroy something yourself. I'd use them for corporate data where following best practices is more important than actual security, but not for something I actually care about.

Answer (score 2):

NIST has created SP 800-164, ["Guidelines on Hardware-Rooted Security in Mobile Devices"](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/drafts/800-164/sp800_164_draft.pdf).
  It is a document that discusses not only the destruction of the device, but other security features that you should be considering, including remote wipe, certificate management, device integrity, using isolation to address various threats, key storage, BYOD, etc.

There is a lot to think about when your organization begins to extend its footprint into the mobile arena, and sanitization is only one aspect.